ECDSA biased nonce with biased middle bits
The paper "Biased nonce sense" (https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/023.pdf) covers key recovery for MSB and LSB, the latter case being handled by doing modular inverse of 2 to the power of the number of bits, which shifts the zero bits to a MSB position and we know how to solve this.
In a talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ssTlSSIJQE&t=863s) one of the authors seems to suggest that it's also trivial to do this for middle bits but this doesn't appear in the paper and it doesn't seem possible to use the same shifting trick since shifting non-zero bits doesn't produce 0-MSbs in the end. Does another documented technique exist?

Just apply a transformation to the matrix and rotate the bits...

@kelalaka I'm sorry I'm not sure what that means. What transformation? Which bits are rotated? This is the matrix construction I have currently, adapted from bitlogik's code mostly for readability.

For this kind of question I always look up Recovering cryptographic keys from partial
information, by example by Gabrielle De Micheli and Nadia Heninger. Table 1 indicates that they cover your case, but I didn't check how much bias they need.

@garfunkel thank you, I don't know why my searches didn't return this paper. I'll get reading!
